# How to tell when a QPushButton is clicked in a QButtonGroup

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qpushbutton

In my project, I have 40 `QPushButton`s all put into a `QButtonGroup` like this:

```
QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(this);
group->addButton(ui->slot_0);
group->addButton(ui->slot_1);
//...
group->addButton(ui->slot_38);
group->addButton(ui->slot_39);
```

Each button is a `QPushButton` that I made checkable. That way only one button can be checked at a time. All works great, but how can I "make a slot" when one of the buttons becomes checked? I don't want to have 40 different slots, one for each button all to end up doing essentially the same thing. Is there any way I can just use the `QButtonGroup` I put them in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jamin and Nikos stated: you should create your own slot to handle the signal emitted by QButtonGroup. It could be something like this:

In the header file:

```
public slots:

void buttonWasClicked(int);
```

In the *.cpp file:

```
void MainWindow::buttonWasClicked(int buttonID)
{
    cout << "You have clicked button: " << buttonID << endl;
}
```

And in the code responsible for creation of the MainWindow (i.e. in constructor but not necessairly) there should be this line:

```
    connect(group, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)), this, SLOT(buttonWasClicked(int)));
```

Be aware that since Qt5 the connect syntax has changed. The syntax I used here is from Qt4. It still works but is deprecated now (for more information please refer to [New Signal Slot Syntax in Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)). Moreover I would suggest going through QButtonGroup class reference as there are other available signals which could suit your needs better than the one I've chosen.

BR

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`QButtonGroup`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qbuttongroup.html) shows a `QButtonGroup::buttonClicked()` signal - have you already tried that one?

The signal comes in two variants - one that gives the `QPushButton` as a parameter (as a `QAbstractButton`), and one that gives the ID of the button in the group.

You can use `connect()` to setup signal and slot connections in your C++ code.

Sometime during the initialization of your window's class (perhaps in the constructor), call this:

```
connect(myButtonGroup, SIGNAL(buttonClicked(QAbstractButton*)), this, SLOT(theSlotThatYouWrite(QAbstractButton*));
```

Where `myButtonGroup` is probably `this->ui->nameOfTheButtonGroup`, and `theSlotThatYouWrite` is a function that you write in your own code, that belongs to your window's class, that returns void and takes a signal `QAbstractButton*` as a parameter (since that's what this specific signal gives as an argument).

Make sure `theSlotThatYouWrite` is under the label "private slots:" or "public slots:" in your class's interface.

Here's a screenshot of actual usage of some signals and slots in my own code.

[image: Click to see full size]

Signals and Slots is something very important to learn, but can be bit of a hill to climb when first trying to understand it!

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't really understand. What would I write the function as?

    void MainWindow::QButtonGroup::buttonClicked();

Comment: @mc360pro It's a signal. You connect it to a slot that takes one of the provided argument types. The passed argument will be the clicked button. If you don't know how to connect signals and slots, there's a tutorial here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Let's just say this, I am sad to say that so far, any signal/slot usage I've been doing is when I right click a button and select "Go to slot." From that point I just add my commands to the function that was created in mainwindow.cpp. So I have no clue how to set up my "own function" without just clicking "go to slot." All I want to do right now is click one of the buttons, and have qDebug tell me what button I clicked. If I can do that I'm set.

Comment: 'Go to slot' doesn't always show all the slots available, and can't be used for everything (imagine dynamically creating widgets on the fly - how will you connect the slots of the widgets that don't exist yet?). You need to use 'connect()' to connect signals and slots - I updated my answer just a little, to give an idea of the usage.